# Understanding private fields in java

Tags: java, private, private-members

Consider this piece of code:

```
class Capsule {
    private int numItems;

    private void moveItemsTo(Capsule that) {
        that.numItems += this.numItems;
        numItems = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        Capsule c = new Capsule();
        c.numItems = 2000;
        c.moveItemsTo( c );
    }
}
```

When I first looked at it, I thought that the `moveItemsTo()` method would cause compilation errors, since it is accessing a private field from another instance of `Capsule`. Also, I thought that even in `main`, accessing the private fields of a newly created instance is not allowed. However, the entire code compiled without any errors, can someone please explain why?

Comment: You are still in the same class and since it´s a valid scope of visibility

Comment: from "another instance". You only have one instance.

Comment: @KevinEsche So if I declared an inner class within `Capsule`, and I declared a private member in that class, it is still accessible by other methods in `Capsule`?